# How to refer to a standard library in a logging configuration file?

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, logging

I need to use a constant defined in the standard library `socket` in a logging configuration file. Problem, when reading the config file with `logging.config.fileConfig()` it ends with:

```
NameError: name 'socket' is not defined
```

My question is very close to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496616/use-of-external-modules-in-a-logging-configuration-file), the difference is that if, as a workaround, I import the missing library (e.g. `socket`) from the main script reading this logging configuration file, it doesn't solve the problem (is this because I use python3?).

Complete logging configuration file:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,mainLogger

[handlers]
keys=mainHandler,nullHandler

[formatters]
keys=defaultFormatter,rawMessageFormatter

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=nullHandler

[logger_mainLogger]
level=DEBUG
handlers=mainHandler
qualname=mainLogger

[handler_nullHandler]
class=NullHandler
args=(50,)

[handler_mainHandler]
class=logging.handlers.SysLogHandler
level=INFO
formatter=defaultFormatter
args=('/dev/log','myapp',socket.SOCK_STREAM)

[formatter_defaultFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s.%(msecs)d %(filename)s: %(funcName)s: %(message)s
datefmt=%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S

[formatter_rawMessageFormatter]
format=%(message)s
datefmt=
```

As another workaround I have tried the solution suggested here: [How to use logging with python's fileConfig and configure the logfile filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649664/how-to-use-logging-with-pythons-fileconfig-and-configure-the-logfile-filename) but this neither works since socket.SOCK_STREAM is not a string (and I don't find any type that could work in the doc: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatspec).

I have also tried to replace `socket.SOCK_STREAM` by 1 (since `socket.SOCK_STREAM == 1` is True) but it doesn't work neither (socket.SOCK_STREAM not being an int...).

I would have liked to avoid converting my logging configuration file into a dictionary (but will do that if there's no other solution).

Comment: You can try with `__import__('socket').SOCK_STREAM` ?

Comment: You mean, inside the logging configuration file? (this leads to a syntax error)

Comment: Strange, I have no syntax error using `1` or `__import__('socket').SOCK_STREAM`.  What is your version of python ?

Comment: This is 3.4.3. What is yours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented [in this section of the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#configuration-file-format), the values are evaluated in the `logging` package's namespace. Hence, you can do something like this:

```
import logging
import socket

# The next line allows 'socket' in the logging package's namespace to pick up
# the stdlib socket module
logging.socket = socket
...
# when the config file is processed, it should work as expected
logging.config.fileConfig(...)
# remove the mapping from the logging package, as not needed any more
# (optional)
del logging.socket
```

Comment: This solves my problem without turning the config file into yaml, so it's better than the solution I found. Thanks!

Comment: Just another comment to point out the differences between the two solutions: with your solution it's possible to use the configuration file I wrote in the question, as is. My solution forces to convert the configuration file into a yaml one, what must make use of `ext://socket.SOCK_STREAM` and not only `socket.SOCK_STREAM`; and the `logging.socket = socket` has no effect on it.

Answer (score 0):

### First solution (should work but doesn't)

Well here there is a partial answer: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.config.html#access-to-external-objects

So I tried this:

```
args=('/dev/log','mathmaker','ext://socket.SOCK_STREAM')
```

But it does not work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 1878, in shutdown
    h.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/handlers.py", line 857, in close
    self.socket.close()
AttributeError: 'SysLogHandler' object has no attribute 'socket'
```

It's like python expects the 'external' object to be an attribute of the class declared in the handler section (e.g. here: `class=logging.handlers.SysLogHandler`).

### Second solution (but requires to turn the config file into yaml):

So, as the mechanism that seems dedicated to solve this problem does not work, I have tried with a configuration file written in yaml, and now it works. It requires to add a dependency (python-yaml or python3-yaml for ubuntu users...) and to load the configuration file as a dictionary:

```
with open(settings.logging_conf_file) as f:
    logging.config.dictConfig(yaml.load(f))
```

and this way, it works.

Here is the same configuration file turned into working yaml (and notice that: 1. the import of `socket` is not required in the main script, looks like python will by itself 'magically' deal with the import; and 2. apart from the fact that yaml is easier to read than the old plain text config file, it also allows to define the keywords in a more readable way):

```
version: 1

formatters:
    rawMessageFormatter:
        format: '%(message)s'
        datefmt: ''
    defaultFormatter:
        format: '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)d %(filename)s: %(funcName)s: %(message)s'
        datefmt: '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'

handlers:
    nullHandler:
        class: logging.NullHandler
    mainHandler:
        class: logging.handlers.SysLogHandler
        level: INFO
        formatter: defaultFormatter
        address: '/dev/log'
        facility: 'myapp'
        socktype: ext://socket.SOCK_DGRAM

loggers:
    root:
        level: INFO
        handlers: [nullHandler]
    mainLogger:
        level: DEBUG
        handlers: [mainHandler]
        qualname: mainLogger
```